# Confusion about the additivity property of measure

Tags: measure-theory

I’m reading about measure theory and bit confused with the definition of a measure. If $F$ is a sigma algebra, then $\mu : F \to [0, \infty]$ is a measure if $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ and $\mu \left( \bigcup_{k =1}^N A_k \right) = \sum_{k = 1}^N \mu(A_k)$. My question is that why is the left hand side a sum and why don’t we have that $\mu \left( \bigcup_{k =1}^N A_k \right) = \bigcup_{k =1}^N \mu(A_k)$?

Comment: note that $\mu:F\to [0,\infty]$, do you think that $\bigcup_{k=1}^N\mu(A_k)$ is a real number? Moreover: the identity $\mu\left(\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb N }A_k\right)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb N }\mu(A_k)$ just hold when the $A_k$ are all disjoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember $\mu$ is a function which takes in a set as input and spits out a number.

We know how to union sets, and we know how to add numbers. Now $\bigcup A_k$ is a set, so $\mu \left ( \bigcup A_k \right )$ should be a number. Individually, though, each $A_k$ is a set, so each $\mu A_k$ is a number. Then countable additivity says that if the $A_k$ are disjoint, we have the following compatibility condition between unions and addition:

$$\mu \left ( \bigcup_k A_k \right ) = \sum_k \mu A_k$$

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Note that if the sets $A_k$ are pairwise disjoint, then we have
$$
\mu \left( \bigcup_{k =1}^\infty A_k \right) = \sum_{k =1}^\infty \mu(A_k)
$$
but if the sequence is increasing; $A_1 \subset A_2, \subset A_3 \subset \dots$, then we have
$$
\mu \left( \bigcup_{k =1}^\infty A_k \right) = \sup_k \mu(A_k) = \lim_{k\to\infty} \mu(A_k)
$$